# Varnish And Magento Redirecting Admin Routers

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, varnish

After Varnish Configuration some of admin `customer routers` are `redirecting to Dash Board`.

I look to console, and saw that first I try to get to my costume controller, but it redirecting with `Status 302` to Admin Home page.

If disable Varnish, everything works fine. Magento log and N-ginx log are clear.
So, I'm sure this is Varnish.

Any advice?

Comment: how does the url of your custom admin page look like? Does it start with `admin` like every other admin link, or with something else?

Comment: Hm, I checked this costume module route, and it starts like front end controller(not as other admin), I will check may be this is the reason

Comment: I'm almost sure that this is the reason. You can either change your module to have the admin controller start with `admin`. This can be a bit painful but it's the right way to do it. The other option is to configure varnish and let your  custom admin URLs `pass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on the comments...
The issue is caused by the custom module admin URL.
It does not start with `admin` (or the configured admin key), but with a custom key like the frontend URLs.
The clean option would be to modify the module to have the admin URL start with `admin`. But this can be painful and time consuming.
The quick and dirty way of doing it is to configure Varnish to let the custom URL `pass`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Marius his answer, in most cases it will be enough in your `default.vcl` to change the next string:

```
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?admin") {
```

with the next one:

```
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(admin|.*adminhtml)") {
```